# Issue resetting form with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having an issue with a form that is built with Ajax. Basically it is one of those forms which populates  as you drill down from a parent select. The problem is once you advance forward a page, and go back the first drop down has its option selected, but the others are not processed and therefore just say "Select a [thing] first". So I'm trying to reset the form when I move back a page.

I have in my document ready the following:

```
$('form[name="Search"]')[0].reset();
```

This works fine in Firefox and Chrome, however IE9 I get the following message:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'reset': object is null or undefined

Does anyone know of a workaround, or suggest a better way to approach this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I did some more thinking about this and used the horrid developer tools in IE.

Turns out that when I hit back, for some stupid reason IE blows away the ID and Name attributes of the . Therefore, I changed the jQuery to:

```
$('form[action="{posturl}"]')[0].reset();
```

That works fine.

Comment: You can probably use: `document.forms[0].reset();`.

Comment: That makes the assumption that it's the first form in the DOM. Thanks anyway.